# how to integrate 2 different server logs to splunk server?

Tags: iptables, syslog, splunk, rsyslog

i want to take various server logs and send it to the splunk server. is that possible?

i assume it has to do something with the rysyslog.conf ... but I have no idea of how to do it?

Comment: Yes its possible. I assume these logs are syslog form, then you directly inject into index.

Comment: This should be on ServerFault, as it's a question about system administration tools rather than about programming.

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can do that, this is what splunk is all about.
Install the universal forwarder and configure the inputs.conf file to gather the data from your files.

http://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/6.2.0/Forwarding/Deploymentoverview